# use specific search with no highlight

Tags: vim

For example I'm in python code and want to jump between classes:

```
nnoremap <buffer> [c /^\s*class\ <CR>
```

How to prevent them from highlight in more elegant way than `:nohl` at the end of command each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid highlighting search matches by using the `:help search()` function or writing your own function.

### With `search()`

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> [c :<C-u>call search('^\s*\zsclass\s')<CR>
```

### With your own function

```
" with ':help :normal'
function! JumpToNextClass()
    normal! /^\s*\zsclass\s
endfunction

" with ':help search()'
function! JumpToNextClass()
    call search('^\s*\zsclass\s')
endfunction

nnoremap <buffer> <silent> [c :<C-u>call JumpToNextClass()<CR>
```

But none of that really matters since Vim already comes with `]]` and `[[`.

Comment: big thanks @romainl for sharing info about `[[`, but I'm wondering, is it possible to patch this and behave in nested definition (in class methods, it won't work for python for ex).

Comment: The default Python ftplugin already has a function that's mapped to `[[` and `]]` which, I'll assume, is already tuned for Python. That function is already pretty generic and can be extracted easily into an even more generic utility function that you can tweak at will.